# Error 500 while using .htaccess file for url rewriting?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Say I've a website www.mywebsite.com. I have several pages in my web directory and those are all with .htm extension. The only page with a .php extension is the index file. Obviously in the menu on every page, there is a link to my "index.php". So whenever I go to Home page from any other page on my website, it shows "www.mywebsite.com/index.php" in the address bar. I want it to be displayed as "http://www.mywebsite.com/" only and not "http://www.mywebsite.com/index.php". How can I do that using .htaccess file. I need a simple and safe method to do it. I searched google, but there was hell lot of complex stuff to understand and to fix this minor problem, and when I tried couple of them (mod rewrite) I always got error 500.

This is the structure of my .htaccess file:

```
Options All -Indexes

<Files /scripts/proc_enq.php>
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Files>
```

Comment: You don't need .htaccess to fix this.  Instead of linking to `index.php` from your nav, link to `/`.

Comment: I already tried this. I've a shared hosting plan, and this redirects me to the root of my shared directory.

Comment: What is your site's document root? Even on a shared hosting plan, you ought to be able to link to a relative URL ...

Comment: If the "site document root" is the default "index.htm" page, then just delete that file, and it should then show index.php as the default page.

Comment: This is something like this:
hosting_root/public_html/mywebsite.com
public_html has 3 add-on domains. Can you tell me how to link to a relative url. I think that can be easily accomplished with some minor configuration in .htaccess file. But I absolutely am new to htaccess. Or suggest something better